# Expand divs to fill page width

Tags: html, css

This `table` results in A and B being spaced out to fill the page width (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ommkg92w/1/)):

```
<table style="width:100%; text-align:center;">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I achieve the same effect using `div` elements? Not like this (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h1x1tuav/1/)):

```
<div style="width:100%; text-align:center;">
  <div style="float:left">A</div>
  <div style="float:left">B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added width 50% to each of the children divs. http://jsfiddle.net/h1x1tuav/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two methods that don't require you to set a width of `50%` on the children elements.

#### CSS tables:

Just set the `display` of the parent element to `table`, and the children elements to `table-cell`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/svyxtbuc/)

```css
.parent {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.parent > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
</div>
```

### Flexbox:

Alternatively, you could also set the `display` of the parent element to `flex`. Then give the children elements a width of `100%`:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/hzmyeebt/)

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
}
.parent > div {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

here are two methods you can use:

http://jsfiddle.net/h1x1tuav/4/

```
<div id="test1">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
</div>
<div id="test2">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
</div>

<style>
#test1 > div {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
}

#test2 {
    width: 100%;
    display:table;
}
#test2 > div {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend accomplishing this without the use of float, as it will remove the divs from the normal flow of the document and require additional html and css.

Instead, display the two children divs as 'inline-block'.

The following will accomplish the same as your setup with tables.

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
    font-size: 0; /* to perfectly align the two children divs */
    width: 100%;
}

.parent > div {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px; /* or whichever size you like */
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to float one left and other right and give those equal widths 50% in this case and text-align center. Try this:

```
<div style="width:100%; text-align:center;">
    <div style="float:left;width:50%;text-align:center">A</div>
    <div style="float:right;width:50%;text-align:center">B</div>
</div>
```